# Vs Code: User Settings: Where are the definition of available properties?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a setting named `"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},`. But I can't seem to be able to find any definition of properties that good be added to this object. Neither in VS Code, nor in Google.

How can I find out what options VS Code has their available?

Answer (score 0):

You can press `Ctrl+Space` (Trigger Suggest command) inside of the brackets `{}` and the VS will show to you what is available to use.

In this case is `"source.organizeImports" : boolean`

Comment: Please, substitute CTRL+Space with the command name from Keyboard Shortcuts of VS Code. In my case, this combination does not do anything.

Comment: So have a look on this help page: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: This is not for me, this is for having more helpful answer for other people. Plus, the link that you sent has a mismatching name for this command.

Comment: The only thing we can add as save action is "source.organizeImports" : boolean ??